# Undefined method 'body' error for RoR tutorial

Tags: ruby, methods, comments

New to ROR and am going through the tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and when adding the comments section, I get an error in the app/views/posts/show.html file that "undefined method `body'. Here is the exact error:

```
undefined method `body' for #<Comment:0x4157430>

Extracted source (around line #37):

34:     </div>
35:     <div class="field">
36:         <%= f.label :body %><br />
37:         <%= f.text_area :body %>
38:     </div>
39:     <div class="actions">
40:         <%= f.submit %>
```

Thanks

Comment: have you migrated the database yet

Comment: Also I think http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ is the best ruby on rails tutorial for beginners

Comment: If you mean doing rake db:migrate in ruby command prompt, yes I have done that.

Comment: yes that is what I was referring to, also you did name the file show.html.erb correct cause you didn't place the erb extension in your question

Comment: What do you mean? You are correct that in the description above, I did not label it correctly, but in the directory it does have the .erb ending.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this exception because there is no body attribute for Comment. This is probably because of one of the following:

- You created the database table Comment without a column called "body"
- You did not run the migration to create the table Comment
- You did not run the migration to create the table Comment on the correct database

Comment: Okay, so I took a look back at the creation of the comment model and migration. I deleted the files that were created for the model and the migration, re created them via rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text post:references and then tried to re migrate the database by rake db:migrate. But I got an error: "... table "comments" already exists: CREATE table "comments"<"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "commenter" varchar<255>, "body" text, "post id".... Does this mean that the database is already there?

Comment: TO WRAP UP QUESTION ---- I ended up re-doing the tutorial, starting from scratch and got it to work. But I believe that you had the correct answer above, but I was not able to reset the migration so that I could remigrate it. Thanks for your response though.